# Redirect all URLs with trailing slash except one

Tags: wordpress, web-config, trailing-slash

My Wordpress environment is running on IIS/Azure.  I have a web.config file that I need help with.  I am already successfully permanently redirecting traffic from all URLs with a trailing slash to the same URL without that slash.  Works great, except I need to negate this rule for one path so I don't break the wp-json (API) functionality supplied by Wordpress.

I took a stab at it, but this negate rule doesn't seem to work.

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^\wp-json$" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The URL I want exempt is still redirecting to a non trailing slash URL where in this case I need the trailing slash to remain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regex guru, but maybe a negative look-ahead could help.  I may not have the matching group correct, though.

```
^((?!wp-json\/).)*$
```

(Based on the discussion here: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word))

Comment: I placed your suggested regex into the relevant part of the rule, but it didn't seem to work:
`<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^((?!wp-json\/).)*$" ignoreCase="true" />`

Answer (score 0):

DJ,

I saw your add on UpWork and thought I'd give you something I found.  They won't let me submit it in a proposal but I don't think it's right to charge for something until it's necessary.

I found this rule at (https://moz.com/community/q/web-config-redirects-not-working-where-a-trailing-slash-is-involved) and thought it might be what you're looking for.  It should work with both a slash and without one.

```
<rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^example_folder" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/newfolder" />
</rule>
```

If you still need help give me a shout and I'd be happy to look at it.  My upwork profile is: https://www.upwork.com/fl/johns770?viewMode=1